# Matching Strings but not substrings where order matters

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to match strings in python:

For example if my phrase is `"long string"`:

I want to match `"long string", "Long StrInG", "long!!!string"` but not `"Long strings"` or `"stringlong"`. ie) I want to match all instances of my string in any string of text with respect to order without respect to capitalization, without capturing substrings.

```
ie) when I do 
string = "hello"
strings = "hellos"
string in strings == True but I don't want this to be true
```

I also want the string to catch any instance in a long sentence separated by spaces or punctuation:

```
ie) string = "long string" should match
"hello ~~~!!!!! long !@#!@#!@ string"

Whitespace also matters - I don't want to match 
string = "longstringlongstring" or "longs trying"
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
text = text where we are seeing if it contains instance of string 
phrase = string to look for in text

cleaned_text = ""
        for char in text:
            if char in string.punctuation:
                char = " "
                cleaned_text += char 
            else:
                cleaned_text += char.lower()
        cleaned_string = " ".join(cleaned_text.split())
        
        counter = 0
        for char in cleaned_string:
            for char2 in phrase:
                if char == char2:
                    counter += 1
        if counter == len(phrase):
            return True
        return False
```

I've realized that I can't use lists because order doesn't matter. Would really appreciate some advice!

Comment: *"long string", "Long StrInG", "long!!!string" but not "Long strings" or "stringlong"* didn't get this part, please explain more? Do you want to tweak some characters?

Comment: I don't understand the second half of the code snippet (the nested loop). Shouldn't you just `return cleaned_string == phrase`? By the way, is `phrase` the same string as `text`?

Comment: With the data you have provided I'm thinking in something like: `def phrase_in_list(phrase, list_phrases): list_phrases = [phrase.lower().replace(' ','').replace('!','') for phrase in list_phrases] phrase = phrase.lower() return phrase in list_phrases` But I consider your question is incomplete, please give us more details.

Comment: Hi I hope I clarified!

Comment: OK, so whitespace and punctuation are significant? In other words, `longstring` and `longs tring` should not match?

Comment: Yea let me clarify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regular expression:

```
import re
import string

# given phrase
phrase = "long string"

# this says what can go between two words of the phrase above
between = "[" + r"\s" + re.escape(string.punctuation) + "]+"

# the pattern
pat = r"\b" + between.join(phrase.split()) + r"\b"
reg = re.compile(pat, flags=re.I)
```

where `between` consists of space(s) (`\s`) and all punctuation characters coming from `string.punctuation` to be seen at least once (due to `[]+` around it). We `re.escape` it because it contains regex metacharacters but we need literal matches there (e.g., `$`). Then the `pat`tern is formed with `join`ing the words of the phrase with this `between` and lastly putting word boundaries (`\b`) on either end to assure exact matching e.g., preventing `long stringS` to match. `re.I` in compiling regex says ignore the case.

For this phrase, `pat` looks like

```
\blong[\s!"\#\$%\&\'\(\)\*\+,\-\./:;<=>\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}\~]+string\b
```

If you were to put one word `phrase`, e.g., `phrase = "this"`, then

```
\bthis\b
```

i.e., no punctuation and space in *between* is imposed because there is only one word.

Lastly, for a 3-word `phrase`, e.g., `phrase = "no escape needed"`

```
\bno[\s!"\#\$%\&\'\(\)\*\+,\-\./:;<=>\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}\~]+escape[\s!"\#\$%\&\'\(\)\*\+,\-\./:;<=>\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}\~]+needed\b
```

i.e., it dynamically forms the regex.

---

Sample runs for testing (if it `is not None`, then there is a match):

```
>>> re.search(reg, "long string") is not None
True

>>> re.search(reg, "Long StrInG") is not None
True

>>> re.search(reg, "long!!!string") is not None
True

>>> re.search(reg, "Long strings") is not None
False

>>> re.search(reg, "stringlong") is not None
False

>>> re.search(reg, "hello ~~~!!!!! long !@#!@#!@ string") is not None
True

>>> re.search(reg, "longstring") is not None
False
```

You can refer to regex details [here](https://regex101.com/r/YZuXun/1).